# Use named parameters in queries Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job in which a step is as follows:

```
<bean id="abstractReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" abstract="true">
    <property name="fetchSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="true"/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="masterReader" parent="abstractReader" abstract="true">
    <property name="fetchSize" value="1000"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="masterDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="abstractWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter" abstract="true">
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="false"/>
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.ColumnMapItemPreparedStatementSetter"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="masterWriter" parent="abstractWriter" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="masterDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tempWriter" parent="masterWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="sql" value="${insert_query}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tempReader" parent="masterReader" scope="step">
    <property name="sql" value="${select_query}"/>
</bean>

<batch:step id="tempStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk commit-interval="100"
                         reader="tempReader"
                         writer="tempWriter"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

Is there a way to bring named parameter support in the queries? Currently JdbcCursorItemReader is using PreparedStatement. (Too many ? in queries now)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way with the `JdbcCursorItemReader` however you can do it with the `JdbcPagingItemReader`.  You can read more about that reader in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html